# want to solve this problem occuring while running django project in postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tutorial
Using the URLconf defined in djangoapi.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/tutorials/int:pk/
api/tutorials/published/
The current path, api/tutorial, didn’t match any of these.

i want to resolve this issue.

Comment: plz put code in question

Comment: Sharing your urls.py config might help

Comment: Just add the missing 's' in tutorials.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.